# Issue in solving d for private key of RSA

Tags: cryptography

I'm struggling in a specific step in the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (EEA) while trying to find the value for d in the private key of the RSA Cryptosystem.

**Calculation of

d = e^(−1) mod φ(n) = 49−1 mod 640 using EEA:

640 = 13 · 49+3

49 = 16 · 3+1

⇔ 1 = 49−16 · 3

= 49−16(640−13 · 49)

= 209 · 49−16 · 640 // the problem

⇒ 49−1 mod 640 ≡ 209.**

How was this equation  49−16(640−13 · 49) converted to 209 · 49−16 · 640 ?

From where did the 209 came?

Comment: When you group all the $49$'s in the expression $49-16(640-13 \times 49)$ ... What do you get ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+ 16 \times 13 = ?
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How many $49$'s & $640$'s are there in $49-16(640-13 \times 49)$ ?

Comment: two 49's and one 640 ig?

Comment: Sort of ? ... But what are the numbers in that they are multiplied by ?

Comment: 640 is multiplied by 16, and 49 is multiplied by 13?

Comment: Yes ! & are you happy with collecting all the $49$'s ?

Comment: yes ;) Thank you!